# ArityException: Wrong number of args (2) passed

Tags: clojure, arity

there are a few related questions on SO but I just can't seem to figure this out. I've got a very simple test code:

```
(ns test
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io]))

(defn tail-file
  [path handler-func]
  (org.apache.commons.io.input.Tailer/create
     (io/file path)
     (proxy [org.apache.commons.io.input.TailerListenerAdapter] []
                   (handle [this line] (handler-func line)))))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (tail-file "c:/tmp/test.txt" println)
  (read-line))
```

This results in:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (2) passed to: core/tail-file/fn--28
```

That's strange because tail-file takes two arguments ([path handler-func]).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should omit `this` in handle definition, since it is declared implicitly as stated in the [docs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/proxy)

> Each method fn takes an additional implicit first arg, which is bound
>   to 'this.

`this` should be explicitly set when using [reify](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reify)

Notice that the error message didnt say there was an error in tail-file, but in some function generated in tail-file: `core/tail-file/fn--28`, namely, fn--28.

Comment: That was the issue, thanks -- after removing 'this', it works now.